# VBA optimization - function with multiple args

Tags: vba, optimization

Hi I am trying to create a function that takes as input a few parameters (irrelevant to the variables optimized) and a variable over which I want to optimize. For example for foo_function(a,b,c,x) I want to pass a,b,c as fixed parameters to foo_function, and finding the minimum of foo_function by changing x. If I was able to work in Matlab or Python this should be relatively easy as a function can return a handle to another function, but that's not possible in VBA. Im trying to use the code in http://www.quantcode.com/modules/mydownloads/singlefile.php?lid=424 
Does anybody have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: As I understand your problem, it seems that recursivity should work fine (i.e., call the function over and over as many times as required; why returning a handle to the function at all?). Can you explain the exact actions which you want to perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `foo_function` to take a parameter array, treat it as a function of 1 variable if only 1 parameter is passed, and if more than 1 is passed, you can store the parameters in static variables. This allows your calling code to set the parameters of `foo_function` before passing its name to optimization code which will treat it as a function of 1 variable.

As a proof of concept, the following function represents a quadratic function:

```
Function quad(ParamArray args()) As Double
    Dim x As Double
    Static a As Double
    Static b As Double
    Static c As Double

    If UBound(args) = 0 Then
        x = args(0)
    Else 'assumes that at least 3 parameters passed
        a = args(0)
        b = args(1)
        c = args(2)
        If UBound(args) = 3 Then
            x = args(3)
        Else
            Exit Function 'function call just initializes statics
        End If
    End If
    quad = a * x ^ 2 + b * x + c
End Function
```

When just 1 is passed, `quad(x)` just evaluates `ax^2 + bx + c` with its current values for those coefficients. If 4 is passed then it is interpreted as a call to `quad(a,b,c,x)`, with the obvious meaning. If just 3 parameters are passed, it is called like a sub:

```
quad a,b,c
```

and doesn't return anything but sets the static parameters to the passed values.

To test it, I wrote a crude numerical differentiation function:

```
Function Derivative(f As String, x As Double, h As Double) As Double
    Derivative = (Application.Run(f, x + h) - Application.Run(f, x)) / h
End Function
```

This approximates the derivative of `f` at the given x value using the given step size.

The following test sub shows how `quad` can be set before passing it the the derivative function:

```
Sub test()
    quad 1, 2, -3 'initializes quad to be x^2 + 2x - 3
    Debug.Print Derivative("quad", 2, 0.0001) 'should be approximately 6
    quad 3, 2, 1
    Debug.Print Derivative("quad", 2, 0.0001) 'now around 14
End Sub
```

Output:

```
6.00010000001205 
14.0003000000277
```

Another, in some ways simpler, approach is to use public variables instead of actual parameters for the parameters to `foo_function` that are irrelevant to the variables being optimized. Then the calling code could assign to these public variables before optimizing. This approach would eliminate the need for parameter arrays but has the drawback of using global-type variables which tend to make programs not sufficiently modular.